# Client to IIS to SQL Server Kerberos authentication

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, kerberos, iis-8, sql-server-2012

I would like to have a setup where my IIS web server sits on a different virtual server from where my SQL Server is installed, and Windows Authentication should be used for all connections. I am currently getting the dreaded `Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'` error which a script running on the IIS server runs a query against the SQL Server, which from all my research points to the double hop problem. I tried setting up SPN's to resolve the problem, but didn't really get anywhere. Here is where I am so far:

- In IIS, I have disabled Anonymous Authentication, and enabled Windows Authentication. The Negotitiate provider has precedence over the NTLM provider
- The application pool is set to use the `NetworkService`
- In ActiveDirectory, both servers (`serveriis` and `serversql`) are set up to allow delegation for all services
- The SQL Server service runs using the `svc_sql` user, which has delegation enabled
- Let's call the domain `corp.domain.com`, and I would like to be able to use `internal` as the URL for the intranet website
- I believe that the web site should not use the application pool credentials, and should use kernel mode, though I am not 100% certain that is correct

I have tried setting up SPN's for the HTTP service with either the machine account, or the service accounts, but it did not work. The only change I managed to produce was that Chrome gave me a `ERR_INVALID_AUTH_CREDENTIALS` error when I used the service account. Setting up SPN's for the database (`MSSQLSvc`) didn't seem to do anything either. I didn't try to use all of the different permutations of machine account/service account for both servers. I have literally spent 2 days trying to get this to work but all the resources I have found online did not point me to the right solution. Both virtual servers are running Windows 2008 R2. I would be very grateful if someone could point me to a solution that does not involve me running IIS on the same server as the database.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question? I am facing the same issue and have been googling for 2 days straight.